# How to determine if 2 polygons are intersected in Gmap.net

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I have 2 polygons. In Gmap.net how can I determine if these 2 polygons intersect each other. What I want to find is if they intersect (true) or do not intersect (false).

Is there any way in Gmap.net polygons to determine this? I could not find a method for this in polygon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find intersection functon in Gmap.net but in there is an intersection finding function in SqlGeometry class in Microsoft.SqlServer.Types library.